# How to Add and configure Democracy Pallet to Substrate Runtime

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet, runtime, democracy

I've made an attempt to incorporate the "pallet-democracy" into my Substrate runtime. In the runtime/Cargo.toml file of my Substrate node template, I've added the following configuration:

> pallet-democracy = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk.git", branch = "polkadot-v1.0.0" }

I also included "pallet-democracy/std" in the list of features. However, I'm struggling to determine the next steps or how to configure the runtime effectively.

I've followed the official substrate documentation, "Add a pallet to the runtime," to follow the process.

Has anyone done this before and can help with the correct procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You should focus on "Review the configuration for Balances" and "Implement the configuration for Nicks" parts. That's what you should do next.

Additionally, there is a kitchensink runtime available that includes all pallets. You can take it as an example.

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/cb944dc54882222453071fc99f2e5014c51823ef/substrate/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1026-L1076